# Computing $\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2})$ (edited)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

In some progress of an exercise, I want to compute $\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2})$. To achieve this, I started from the sequence
$$
0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(-1) 
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}} 
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L
\rightarrow 0
$$

where $L$ is a line in the projective plane $\mathbb{P^2}$. Then taking the Hom sheaf funtor $\mathcal{Hom}(-,\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2})$, it goes to
$$
0\rightarrow \mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_L,\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2}) 
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2}
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(1)
\rightarrow \mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2})
\rightarrow 0
$$
Now $\mathcal{Hom}(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}})=0$(Thanks to the comment), so I have an short sequence

$$
0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2}
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(1)
\rightarrow \mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2})
\rightarrow 0$$
Next, recall the first basic short exact sequence with tensoring $\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2}(2)$, I also have
$$
0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2}(1)
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(2)
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L(2)
\rightarrow 0$$
Connecting those sequences
\begin{eqnarray}
0&\rightarrow &\qquad\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2}
&\rightarrow &\quad\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(1)
&\rightarrow &\quad\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2})
&\rightarrow &0\\\\
0&\rightarrow &\quad\mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2}(1)
&\rightarrow &\quad\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P^2}}(2)
&\rightarrow &\quad\qquad\mathcal{O}_L(2)
&\rightarrow &0
\end{eqnarray}
and using snake lemma(Sorry, I can't write vertical down arrows), I got the third sequence
$$
0\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L(1)
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_L(2)
\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_p(2)
\rightarrow 0$$
consequently,
$$
\mathcal{Ext}^1(\mathcal{O}_L, \mathcal{O}_\mathbb{P^2})\cong\mathcal{O}_L(1).
$$
Are those steps are correct?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why do you think those maps are the zero map? They are induced by the inclusion map of the ideal of $L$, so I expect (albeit have not computed) that those maps are also multiplication by the equation of $L$.

Comment: Because I have to get the consequence, isomorphism. If the the last map of that sequence is just an isomorphism, isn't the second map zero from the exactness? But I also think it is not a zero map, actually. So I want to find other side steps to get the isomorphism correctly..

Comment: I would say that for $R$-modules, if $T$ is torsion and $F$ is free then $Hom_R(T,F) = 0$. This should gives $\mathcal Hom(O_L, O_{\mathbb P^2}) = 0$ .

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Hemelsoet. That was what I wondered too.

Comment: @nida08 OK, your edit looks good, but given that the two vertical arrows on the left are equalities (genuine equalities, not isomorphisms!) is the snake lemma argument really necessary? You know that the map $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2} \to \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^2}(1)$ is multiplication by the equation of $L$, so you know the cokernel is $\mathcal O_{L}(1)$, and you've already identified this as the Ext sheaf. I don't think there's even invocation of some abstract nonsense about uniqueness of universal objects here because you've identified the two sheaves as the cokernel of the *same* morphism.

Comment: @Tabes bridges Oh...It's true. Since I got the short exact sequence at the first step, it was actually done and so the snake lemma-argument is unnecessary.. Thank you for your kindness comment.